# Time Zone Formula

Tags: java

I am making a practice where i need to calculate the hour based on a difference of time zone so i basically came up with the following code:

```
System.out.print("What is the time difference, in hours, between your home and your destination? ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int hoursDif = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    int mid;
    if (hoursDif < 0){
        mid = 24 + hoursDif;
    }
    else{
        mid = hoursDif;
    }
    int noon;
    if (hoursDif+12 < 24){
        noon = hoursDif + 12;
    }
    else{
        noon = hoursDif + 12 +- 24;
    }
    System.out.print("That means that when it is midnight at home it will be " + mid + ":00 and noon: " + noon);
```

But the problem is that the course is only beginning and havent see loops yet, so anyone knows if there is a way to get the same output but without the if  statements?

Comment: Do you have to output Midnight and Noon time differences between 2 zones?

Comment: This is just a toy implementation for an assignment, but in real life you can't depend on time offsets being an integer number of hours. You might want to read through http://FalsehoodsAboutTime.com.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple with a proper `LocalDateTime` object.

```
System.out.print("What is the time difference, in hours, between your home and your destination? ");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int hoursDif = input.nextInt();
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
int mid = localDateTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS).plusHours(hoursDif).getHour();
int noon = localDateTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS).plusHours(12).plusHours(hoursDif).getHour();
System.out.print("That means that when it is midnight at home it will be " + mid + ":00 and noon: " + noon);
```

You just get the current time, truncate it to DAYS (so it's 00:00:00) and then add the time you entered.